# Updating a Temporary Table with many columns from Multiple Tables on Different Servers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, optimization, join

I have a stored procedure which goes to three different servers and gets values from all of them something like this:

```
 Update #temp 
 set col1.temp = t1col1.table 
 from #temp  inner join table1.Server1 on temp.id = table1.id
 Update #temp 
 set col2.temp = t2col2.table 
 from #temp  inner join table2.Server1 on temp.id = table2.id
 Update #temp 
 set col3.temp = t3col3.table 
 from #temp  inner join table3.Server1 on temp.id = table3.id
```

Note: Before the above update statement I have updated my temp with all the values I had on the Local Server

That's how I'm updating the table. To better optimize and get much faster results, I did this:

```
update #temp
set  col1.temp = t1col1.table,
col2.temp = t2col2.table,
col3.temp = t3col3.table 
from #temp inner join table1.server1 on temp.id= table1.id
leftjoin table2.server1 on temp.id = table2.id
leftjoin table3.server1 on temp.id = table3.id
```

The basic idea I had was to reduce the time it takes for multiple updates to a single update. This stored procedure generates around 300,000 rows and around 30 columns from 3 different servers.

I have a few basic questions:

1. Is it better to use multiple UPDATE statements or a single UPDATE statement with multiple JOINs
2. If I can use a single UPDATE statement than is it better to write updates using INNER JOINs or LEFT JOINs
3. Are JOINs time consuming when dealing with huge amounts of data? (note: all the servers and tables I get my columns from have millions of records) Which JOIN is better...?
4. I have tried using INNER JOINs but it didn't work for table 2 and table 3; it only worked for table1

The above UPDATE statements are for server 1, they are the same as for server 2 and server 3, as they have some values I need.

Comment: What convention are you using to pull data from other servers, Linked Servers(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)?

Comment: I dont understand what convention you are talking about, but this is how i select the value select from  [server].tablename

Comment: @JordanBelfort Do you mean [database].tablename?  I could be absolutely wrong here but it sounds more like you have multiple databases on the same server.  Then it would make sense that you are pulling data from multiple places without the use of linked servers or some other convention.  So server 1 would be DB1, server 2 would be DB2, etc...

Comment: no it is like [server].Database.TableName you can do a select i guess they are linked servers

Answer (score 0):

Based on your predicted data set, my personal history with Linked Servers (7 SQL instances on 4 physical servers, some tables capping at 50-100M rows/server), and some excellent TechNet articles, I recommend creating a view similar to

```
select t1col1.table, t2col2.table, t3col3.table 
from  table1 on temp.id= table1.id
leftjoin table2 on table1.id = table2.id
leftjoin table3 on table1.id = table3.id
```

and then perform the singular join to the view across your link servers. Each join essentially creates a new OLE connection and the SQL engine could decide to pull the whole data set locally to perform the join. Do as much on server that holds the data as possible, it will make all the difference with performance.

Good reading:

> [linked-server-behavior-when-used-on-join-clauses](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pfelatam/archive/2011/09/07/linked-server-behavior-when-used-on-join-clauses.aspx)
>
> [Linked Servers (Database Engine)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Comment: How will this update my #temp table,  and all the Select statement is only for one server to update..

Comment: and even my old method is the same, i cant use this again;